# can we create two Parquet files using SparkSQL (DataFrame)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, parquet, partition

I am loading table from Netezza to Hive. Table size is huge, and its creating parquet file which size is more than 1 GB.

Is there a way that while loading a table I can mention that it should create two parquet files instead of one?

```
val connectionProperties = new Properties() 
connectionProperties.put("driver", driver) 
connectionProperties.put("user", user) 
connectionProperties.put("password", password) 
val prodDF = sparkSession.read 
  .jdbc( url = url, table = s"(${(sql)}) t1", properties = connectionProperties )
```

Comment: Are you using `numPartitions` when connecting to Netezza as described in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html? If yes, can you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: No, I am not using numPartitions ,  Please find my code sample.

Comment: then perhaps you can set `numPartitions=2` to have 2 files.

Comment: ok i will give a try that but is there anyway we can make it dynamic according to table data size ?